# In a class template how to detect if the template parameter is an enumeration type?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, enums, detect

In a class template, how to detect if the template parameter is an enumeration type ?

Here is a simplified example of what I would like to do : http://ideone.com/3CafY. How would you implement IsTEnum() so that the output is correct ?

I feel there should be a boost function that solves this problem, however I am not allowed to use boost (nor the standard library std:: functions) in my current project.
Nonetheless, I would also be interested to know both methods using boost or not (even if the solution does not handle pointer or const types).

Answer (score 7):

You can use C++11's [std::is_enum](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum) for that purpose. You are right in that boost has [the same solution](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_enum.html). If you cannot use boost or C++11, you can always look at the implementations for inspiration.

Comment: Indeed I cannot use C++11 neither. Thank you for the link to boost function, its implementation seems to require the inclusion of other boost functions (is_arithmetic, is_reference..). I would be interested to know the "smallest implementation" in term of code volume.

Comment: I just glanced at several of the implementations, this is non-trivial.  If you want a portable and mostly complete solution use you'll have to extract it from boost or a std library.

Comment: For a discussion on the topic see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/iYuYR1yAT1s)

Comment: @wil it is a non-trivial task. If you only want to detect enums you may be able to simplify what is done in boost. I might have a look at that later.

Answer (score 1):

Before C++11 there are detectors for built-in types and types convertible to `int`

```
template <typename E> struct IntTest
{
    static char eval(...)
    {
        return ' ';
    }
    static int eval(int z)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    static const bool knowsInt = sizeof(int) == sizeof(eval(*(E*)0));
};
```

`IntTest<enum_type>::knowsInt` will return true for some `enum_type`. When you exclude built-in types and classes with implicite conversion to `int` like

```
class R
{
public:
    int z;
    operator int()
    {
        return z;
    }
};
```

you can assume that you have an enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use C++11 then write:

```
#include <tr1/type_traits>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   cout << tr1::is_enum<int>::value << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

The namespace tr1 includes some header files from C++11 which can be used in pre standard C++.

Comment: Ufortunately I cannot include <tr1/type_traits> in my project. I think the C++ dialect it uses might be ISO/IEC 14882:1998.